# Is it possible to represent the real-time position data (float) received using socket_io in the flutter app as a time-position graph?

Tags: flutter, graph, websocket, socket.io

"Hello, I am a student who is interested in flutter and studying.
I would like to output the float data value received through websocket on the screen in real time,
I'm asking you what direction the code should be structured in, whether the process of implementing it as code should be implemented as follows.
Here's the code I've written so far!"

I have attached the codes I have written so far.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PT0f.png)

Comment: Please add the code as text. Use ` at the beginning and end of the code block.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The exact architecture you use comes down to the problem at hand and what your personal preference is. There is no right or wrong, each has its own strengths. With that said, I would advise looking at [SOLID](https://www.baeldung.com/solid-principles) principles and apply it to your use case, if applicable and useful.